# Open interest and short selling

Tags: options, open-interest

Open interest of SPY: https://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=SPY+Options

If someone sell short a contract the open interest adds up or down?
The open interest on yahoo finance is a reliable Information of how many contracts are really opened or they misses someone?

Answer (score 2):

Options are in zero net supply (like futures and other derivatives), so for evry long there is a short and for every short there is a long. The open interest is the sum of the longs which also equals the sum of the short positions.